# Download all variables from all tables in the American Community Survey (ACS) 2013-2017 summary file for all census block groups in a state

Tags: r, census

I've downloaded the raw summary file data for the American Community Survey (ACS) 2013-2017 for Kansas here: https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/acs/summary_file/2017/data/5_year_by_state/Kansas_Tracts_Block_Groups_Only.zip

I then unzipped it into the folder "acs_2017_5_year" in my working directory and ran this code:

```
library(totalcensus)

#### raw acs data import ####
set_path_to_census("acs_2017_5_year")

trying_acs <- read_acs5year(
  year = 2017,
  states = "KS",
  table_contents = "*",
  summary_level = "block group", 
  with_margin = TRUE
)
```

I then get this error:

```
Error in read_acs5year_geoheaders_(year, states, table_contents, geo_headers,  : 
  The table content reference * does not exist.
```

What can I do to download all the variables in all the tables for Kansas?  What goes in the `table_contents` field?  If no simple way to indicate "all the variables!" exists, is there a handy list of all the variable names somewhere that I could chuck into a massive vector?  I haven't been able to find either one.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have already downloaded everything for KS 2017 ACS5year. In order to extract particular table_contents (or variables), you need to provide the references to argument `table_contents`. Run `search_tablecontents("acs5")` to find out the references. There are over 26000 variables so it is not realistic to extract all of them into one data.table.